# Group operands by logical connective precedence from Python list

Tags: python, list, nested, grouping

My input is:

```
['A', '&', 'B', '|', 'C', '|', '!', 'D', '^', 'E', '&', 'F']
```

which has operands (A-F) and connectives that has precedence according to:

1. !
2. &
3. ^
4. |

I need to group items so that output in this case would be:

```
[[['A', '&', 'B'], '|', 'C'], '|', [[['!', 'D'], '^', ['E', '&', 'F']]]]
```

So first unary negations (!) are grouped. Then binary conjunctions (&), then exclusive ors (^) and finally disconjunctions (|).

Is there a neat way to do this with Python?

**Example code, which should do the work but not so neat:**

```
def grp(lst, operator='|'):
    i, l, r = 0, len(lst), []
    while i < l:
        item = lst[i]
        if item == operator:
            if item == '!':
                r.append([item, lst[i+1]])
            else:
                r[-1] = [r[-1], item, lst[i+1]]
            i+=1
        else:
            r.append(item)
        i+=1
    return r

lst = ['A', '&', 'B', '|', 'C', '|', '!', 'D', '^', 'E', '&', 'F']
print(grp(grp(grp(grp(lst, '!'), '&'), '^'), '|'))
# -> [[[['A', '&', 'B'], '|', 'C'], '|', [['!', 'D'], '^', ['E', '&', 'F']]]]
```

Comment: I'm holding my breath for a "neat" solution. You probably have to write your own parser.

Comment: I think you should create a dictionary which keys are the operators and values its preference. Then, you will have to implement your own algorithm using post-fix notation probably in order to process that list.

Comment: As already mentioned by @juanpa.arrivillaga a parser might be good choice - there is a [sample implementation of LL parser in python wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser#Parser_implementation_in_Python)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is semi-neat. It is short and simple.
(Not awefully efficient, though)

```
tokens = ['A', '&', 'B', '|', 'C', '|', '!', 'D', '^', 'E', '&', 'F']

# operators and number of operands they bind (one to the right, rest to the left):
ops = [ ('!',1), ('&',2), ('^',2), ('|',2) ]

def rindex(lst, x):
    return len(lst) - 1 - lst[::-1].index(x)

for op, n in ops:
    while True:
        try:
            i = rindex(tokens, op)
        except ValueError:
            break
        # "wrap" it:
        tokens[i-n+1 : i+2] = [ tokens[i-n+1 : i+2] ]

tokens
=> [[[['A', '&', 'B'], '|', 'C'], '|', [['!', 'D'], '^', ['E', '&', 'F']]]]
```

EDIT: using `rindex`, courtesy of @coproc.

Comment: looks really nice - but gives a wrong result for `tokens = ['!', '!', 'A']` :  `[['!', '!'], 'A']` (instead of `['!', ['!', 'A']]` )

Comment: there is an easy fix: instead of taking the index of the first occurence, one can take the index of the last occurence of `op` in `tokens`. Unfortunately there is no method `rindex`, but e.g. `i = len(tokens) - 1 - tokens[::-1].index(op)` works

Comment: Same problem exists if other symbols are repeated similar way? Maybe preprocessing input is required anyway... good point anyway!

Comment: @MarkokraM are you talking to me? (without `@coproc` I do not get a notification) I would expect that with my proposed fix the code should now work also for any unary operator with arbitrary precedence. Why not test it? :-) Other symbols may not be repeated in a valid token sequence.

Comment: Yes @coproc I was just thinking that negation of negation would simply remove both operands in logic. So by sanitizing input your fix wouldn't be needed. That said, I tested it works well, so if shx2 adds it to the code, I would accept it.

Comment: @coproc I also noticed that if you take off ! from input, your fix gives slightly different grouping than original answer method. It is about the left / right order of grouping I suppose. Can you verify it? (input: ['A', '&', 'B', '|', 'C', '|', 'D', '^', 'E', '&', 'F'])

Comment: @MarkokraM sure, the restriction to forbid double application of `!` makes the problem easier. But then you would need extra code to ensure/enforce this restriction. And it is not part of your question ... And then there might be other unary operators that do not cancel themselves, but for which one might be tempted to use this simple code also. So I think the answer should be edited.

Comment: I added @coproc's fix. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkokraM using `index` or `rindex` also somehow dictates left- or right-associativity. (using index: `['A', '|', 'B', '|', 'C']` becomes `[['A', '|', 'B'], '|', 'C']`, using rindex it becomes `['A', '|', ['B', '|', 'C']]`.) For commutative operators (as in your case) this does not make a difference, but for non-commutative operators like `-` one usually assumes left-associativity, which does not go together with using `rindex`. Maybe a small drawback of this simple solution.

Comment: Yes, thats what I suspected. Thanks for clarification @coproc

Answer (score 1):

This solution generalizes the idea of the `grp` function and because of its recursive structure it only needs one invocation:

```
def lastIndex(lst, x):
    return len(lst) - 1 - lst[::-1].index(x)

def parse(l, binOps=('|', '^', '&')):
  assert len(l) > 0, "malformed input"
  if len(l) == 1:
    assert l[0] != '!' and not l[0] in binOps, "malformed input"
    return l[0]
  if len(binOps) > 0:
    binOp = binOps[0]
    try:
      opPos = lastIndex(l, binOp) # for left-associativity of binary operators
      return [parse(l[:opPos], binOps), binOp, parse(l[opPos+1:], binOps[1:])]
    except ValueError:
      return parse(l, binOps[1:])
  assert l[0] == '!', "malformed input"
  return ['!', parse(l[1:], binOps)]

parse(['A', '&', 'B', '|', 'C', '|', '!', 'D', '^', 'E', '&', 'F'])
# -> [[['A', '&', 'B'], '|', 'C'], '|', [['!', 'D'], '^', ['E', '&', 'F']]]
```

Note that the parse function itself does not know anything about the binary operators (except for the default argument added for convenience here). The binary operators and their precedence can be specified arbitrarily by the second argument. Splitting the parsed tokens at the last occurence of a binary operator makes the grouping left-associative. (Splitting the parsed tokens at the first occurence would make the grouping right-associative, which is not the usual default and which gives unexpected results for non-commutative operators.)

Comment: Not too bad either. I have not tried performance of these two approaches, but simple is better since in reality I need to add more functionality to the algo. It is going to get complicated anyway, so I prefer simple start. On the other hand your code might be more straightforward to transform to other languages like js and php. Thus +1.

Comment: I actually noticed that your implementation gives parsing check further than I expected. Arbitrary conseguensing operators like ! & or ^ & ! etc. are caught by assert part. This solves the whole pre sanitizing thing. Not bad at all. While loop takes 10microsecs. Your recursive one 13microsecs. But if sanitize routine is added it would even the cases.

Comment: @MarkokraM I have added two more parsing checks that should make the checking complete. Since `parse(['A'])` gives `'A'` I think there is no natural default for parsing the empty list. Also missing operator arguments or mistaking operators as atoms should be avoided now. (before `parse(['|','|','A'])` would simply give `['|','|','A']`)